# Image Stretch and crop to fit the exact size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` containing image inside it,the `div` overflow is hidden so they image will be cropped if there is excess width or height, it was working fine but some times it does not. what is wrong ? i have tried this

Jquery

```
 $("#covorpic").on("load" , function(){
    var covwidth = $("#covorpic").width();
    if (covwidth>750){
        $("#covorpic").css({"margin-left":(750  -  $("#covorpic").width())/2});

    }
    else{
        $("#covorpic").css({"width" : "750px" });

        $("#covorpic").css({"margin-top":(200  -  $("#covorpic").height())/2});

    }
});
```

html

```
<div class="covor_cont">
   <img id="covorpic" src="someimage.ext">
</div>
```

css

```
 .covor_cont{
   max-height: 200px;
   min-height:130px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align: center;
   }
#covorpic{
   height: 200px;
  }
```

Comment: @snapshoe i mean streach

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in CSS, try

```
.covor_cont {
    width: 750px;
}
#covorpic {
    max-width: 95%;
}
```

Set the container to an exact size, set the max-width on the image to shrink if larger than container.

Comment: It is not about the width , once I streach the image I want to make the center part visible,